# Django Rest Framework get URI template for view-details from view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, uri

I want to get the URI template for a Django view. As in the [Internet Standards URI template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), not the Django url template tag. So for example for a urls.py with:

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'collections', views.CollectionViewSet)
```

and view.py with

```
from restframework import viewsets

class CollectionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Collection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CollectionSerializer
    lookup_field='name'

def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
    <...code overriding list...>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to, from the list function, get the uri template like so:

```
'http://localhost:8000/api/collections/{name}/'
```

I have tried using rest framework's 'reverse', which is an extension of a django 'reverse' function; like this:

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
field=self.lookup_field
url = reverse('collection-detail', args=['temp'], request=request)
url = url.replace('temp', '{' + field + '}')
```

This is so clunky though! Is there a better way?? Thank you :)

I tried to google this but all the results are about the url template tag, which is something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any solution provided out of the box but I know there is a command in the django-extensions that gives a way to print all urls patterns and their params,
you could dig a solution from how they did it:
[Code extract for show_urls command](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/show_urls.py)

```
# Basicly they load urls configurations
# ...
urlconf = __import__(getattr(settings, 'ROOT_URLCONF'), {}, {}, [''])
# ...
# then you can have a look on the patterns
print(urlconf.urlpatterns)
```

Sorry if this seems too 'hacky' but perhaps it could help you.

Comment: Hey, thanks this seems helpful. I'll have to dig a bit to see whether I can make it work. Will revert.

Comment: Upvoted. See my answer for a different solution I found. Thank you for the help.